# Count number of distinct particuliar right columns in a left join

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

Given the following 2 tables:

```html
<div style="float:left;width:48%;">
<label>Table1</label>
<table>
  <thead style="background:green;">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="background:yellow;">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:48%;">
  <label>Table2</label>
<table>
  <thead style="background:green;">
    <tr>
      <th>t1ID</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="background:yellow;">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a join that also contains a count of distinct matches.

So I'd be looking for a result set like this:

```html
<label>Results</label>
<table>
  <thead style="background:green;">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ColorCount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="background:yellow;">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My basic query is:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Table2.Color) AS ColorCount FROM
Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.t1ID
```

However this only return a row of data like:

```
1    Apple    3
```

The above is counting all the distinct colors, rather than the 2 red(1) and 1 green(1) (1+ 1) = 2;

It appears the distinct is forcing the query to distinct all the values from Table2 rather than those that match the conditions of the join.  I'm banging my head here.  Thinking about my end goal, I can definitely achieve this using sub queries, but If I don't need to use them in tandem with a join, that'd be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT ID , T1.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT T2.Color) as ColorCount
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.t1ID
GROUP BY ID,T1.NAME
```

Comment: ah, pardon.  I need distinct values for the Color.  If there was an extra 1 Red in table 2, I would get a result of 3 for color Count.  I'll modify the question.

Comment: @Rooster, updated the answer, need to add DISTINCT inside COUNT

Comment: that returns 1 for ColorCount on all `Apple` results

Comment: @Rooster, here is the sql fiddle, which matches with your data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbe47/1

Comment: ah.  I'm not naming my tables T1 and T2.  Maybe that's why mines failing.  Unfortunately I'm in a meeting and can't check til afterwards.

Comment: ah, I see, I was refactoring your query to meet my actual data and missed that you weren't grouping by T2.Color anywhere, but rather by props only from table 1.  Working great now.  THanks.